# Internal State Changes After try{} Block

Tags: perl, object, try-catch, state, marpa

I'm working with [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/module/JKEGL/Marpa-R2-2.058000/pod/Marpa_R2.pod), and am trying to catch errors using [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny). I am puzzled because when I put the parsing code into a `try` block, the result of the `value` method is `undef`. Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dumper;
use Try::Tiny;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new(
    {
        source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),
            :default ::= action => ::array
            :discard ~ ws
            ws ~ [\s]+
            :start ::= Name
            Name ::= Foo
            Foo ~ [\w]+
END_OF_SOURCE
    }
);
my $reader = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new(
    {
        grammar => $grammar,
    }
);
my $input = 'foo';
try{
    $reader->read(\$input);
}catch {
    warn "caught error: $_";
}
my $value = $reader->value;
print Dumper $value;
```

I was going a little nuts trying to figure out what was the grammar, and then I realized that removing the `try` block made the value of `$reader->value` non-null. Even if I assign `$value` within the `try` block, it becomes `undef` when the block is finished:

```
my $value;
try{
    $reader->read(\$input);
    $value = $reader->value;
}catch {
    warn "caught error: $_";
}
print Dumper $value;
```

This seems to mean that if I want to catch errors with `Try::Tiny`, I have to put ALL of my processing of `$value` into the `try` block, which is inconvenient.

Can anyone tell me what is causing this (I'd like an explanation of how this is possible in Perl)? And is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try{
    $reader->read(\$input);
}catch {
    warn "caught error: $_";
}                               <------ missing semicolon
my $value = $reader->value;
```

Keep in mind that `try` is not actually a control structure. `try` and `catch` are simply subs with the `&@` prototype. (I imagine that `catch` returns some form of object.) As such, the above code is equivalent to

```
&try(sub { ... }, &catch(sub { ... }, my $value = $reader->value));
```

Notice how the assignment to `$value` is being done before the `try`?